# Rails JSON and XML Serialization include Micro Seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json

Is it possible to include the micro seconds when serializing a Rails object for 'datetime' fields? For example:

```
{ 
  "created_at":"2011-05-27T19:49:43.123456Z", 
  "updated_at":"2011-05-27T19:49:43.654321Z", 
  "..."
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the default JSON formatting which is set in [this file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L276).
The format that you want to use would be this

```
strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%6N %z')
```

And you can patch JSON's DateTime output like this

```
class DateTime
  def as_json(options = nil)
    strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%6N %z')
  end
end
```

And here is a reference of the fractional time references available in strftime()
    %N - Fractional seconds digits, default is 9 digits (nanosecond)

```
%3N millisecond (3 digits)
%6N microsecond (6 digits)
%9N nanosecond (9 digits)
```

Comment: I am using a database that stores microseconds. I just need the serialization.

Comment: Is it storing it as microseconds in the db?

Comment: Yes. `user.created_at.usec = 123456` and `user.updated_at.usec = 654321`

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, I will see what I can turn up here.

Comment: Alright it looks like to_json uses ISO_8601 by default. You want to overide the default formatting set here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L276